# Output different for the same instruction - move and copy ctor

Tags: c++, c++17

Can someone please explain me what is really happening here, because I'm a bit confused.

Here is my code

```
{
public:
    MetaData (int size, const std::string& name)
        : _name( name )
        , _size( size )
    {
        std::cout << "Call of Metadata(int, string) ctor " << std::endl;
    }

    // copy constructor
    MetaData (const MetaData& other)
        : _name( other._name )
        , _size( other._size )
    {
        std::cout << "Call of MetaData(const MetaData&) copy ctor" << std::endl;
    }

    MetaData& operator= (const MetaData& other)        
    {           
        std::cout << "Call of MetaData& operator= (const MetaData&) ctor" << std::endl; 
        _size = other._size;
        _name = other._name;

        return *this;
    }
    // move constructor
    MetaData (MetaData&& other)
        : _name( std::move(other._name) )
        , _size( other._size )
    {
        std::cout << "Call of MetaData (MetaData&&) move ctor" << std::endl;
    }

    MetaData& operator= (MetaData&& other)
    {
        _size = other._size;
        _name = std::move(other._name);
return *this;
    }

    std::string getName () const { return _name; }
    int getSize () const { return _size; }

    private:
    std::string _name;
    int _size;
};

class ArrayWrapper
{
public:
    // default constructor produces a moderately sized array
    ArrayWrapper () : _metadata( 64, "ArrayWrapper" )
    {
        std::cout << "Call of ArrayWrapper() default ctor " << std::endl;
    }

    ArrayWrapper (int n) : _metadata( n, "ArrayWrapper" )
    {
        std::cout << "Call of ArrayWrapper(int) default ctor " << std::endl;
    }

    // move constructor
    ArrayWrapper (ArrayWrapper&& other) : _metadata( std::move(other._metadata) )
    {   
        std::cout << "Call of ArrayWrapper (ArrayWrapper&&) move ctor" << std::endl;                
    }

     ArrayWrapper& operator= (ArrayWrapper&& other)       
    {   
        std::cout << "Call of ArrayWrapper& operator=(ArrayWrapper&&) assignement ctor" << std::endl;   

        _metadata = std::move(other._metadata);         
        return *this;
    }


    ArrayWrapper& operator= (const ArrayWrapper& other)        
    {   
        std::cout << "Call of ArrayWrapper& operator= (const ArrayWrapper&) assignement ctor" << std::endl; 
        _metadata = other._metadata ;

        return *this;
    }

    // copy constructor
    ArrayWrapper (const ArrayWrapper& other) : _metadata( other._metadata )
    {
        std::cout << "Call of ArrayWrapper (const ArrayWrapper&) copy ctor" << std::endl;        
    }


    ~ArrayWrapper ()
    {
        std::cout << "Delete of ArrayWrapper" <<std::endl;        
    }
private:    
    MetaData _metadata;
};
```

In the main I do some test:

```
int main()
{           
    std::vector<ArrayWrapper> v;
    v.push_back(ArrayWrapper());
    v.push_back(ArrayWrapper());

    return 0;
}
```

The first `v.push_back(ArrayWrapper())` output:

```
Call of Metadata(int, string) ctor
Call of ArrayWrapper() default ctor
Call of MetaData (MetaData&&) move ctor
Call of ArrayWrapper (ArrayWrapper&&) move ctor
Delete of ArrayWrapper
```

what is for me the output I was expecting.
And here is what is confusing me, I was expecting the second instruction to output exactly the same thing but here is what I get:

```
Call of Metadata(int, string) ctor
Call of ArrayWrapper() default ctor
Call of MetaData (MetaData&&) move ctor
Call of ArrayWrapper (ArrayWrapper&&) move ctor
Call of MetaData(const MetaData&) copy ctor
Call of ArrayWrapper (const ArrayWrapper&) copy ctor
Delete of ArrayWrapper
```

Why the copy ctor  of ArrayWrapper is getting called whereas in the first instruction it does not ?

To me to the output for the second v.push_back(ArrayWrapper()) should have been:

```
Call of Metadata(int, string) ctor
Call of ArrayWrapper() default ctor
Call of MetaData (MetaData&&) move ctor
Call of ArrayWrapper (ArrayWrapper&&) move ctor
Delete of ArrayWrapper //to delete the temporary moved
```

What am I getting wrong ?

Comment: First thing I can see is that your move assignment of MetaData does not return anything.

Comment: You seem to forget that `std::vector` is a *dynamic* "array" which grows as you add elements to it. Part of this "growing" means that the old data (the element from the first `push_back`) needs to be copied to the newly allocated larger memory.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude old data needs to be copied or moved (if your move constructor is `noexcept` (since c++11)).

Comment: @AshwaniDausodia Yes indeed, I edited my post to return ```*this```in the move assignement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because capacity of vector changes in the second call. It means that vector has no space left for more elements and it allocates new memory (bigger than the old) to store the new item. In the process, it also copies the existing items from old allocated memory to the new one. That is why you see a extra copy constructor of `ArrayWrapper` being called.

```cpp
int main() {
    std::vector<ArrayWrapper> v;
    v.push_back(ArrayWrapper());
    std::cout << v.capacity() << std::endl;
    v.push_back(ArrayWrapper());
    std::cout << v.capacity() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

You can avoid that copy by making you move constructor `noexcept`.

Comment: Thank you @Ashwani, indeed it is due to how ```std::vector``` works!!